# Укажите на ошибку в цикле for.

Tags: c

Укажите на ошибку в цикле for.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
    int sum=0;  
    int i=1;

    for (i <= 2) {  
        sum += i;  
        i += 1;  
    }  
}
```

/home/zavulon/Programming/Projects/CС++/С/test.c: В функции «main»:
/home/zavulon/Programming/Projects/CС++/С/test.c:6:16: ошибка: expected «;» before «)» token
/home/zavulon/Programming/Projects/CС++/С/test.c:6:16: ошибка: expected expression before «)» token

Comment: нерусским языком же написано: 

>expected «;» before «)» token

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Почитайте, как правильно оформляется конструкция for в языках C/C++.

Попробуйте изменить так:

```
for (; i <= 2; )
```

Или вовсе написать в полной форме:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int sum=0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i += 1) {  
        sum += i;            
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Посмотрите внимательно точки с запятой! Всё должно работать.